# Is it Possible to Pass Edittext Value from one activity to another activity without using Intent

Tags: android, android-intent

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Page.class); 
intent.putExtra("arg", getText);
startActivity(intent);


//second activity:

String passedArg = getIntent().getExtras().getString("arg");
enteredValue.setText(passedArg);
```

> To get value from one activity to another activity without using
>   intents....?? I want to show edittext passed data in other activity
>   edittext but without using intent...?? Kindly help me is it possible
>   or not....??

Comment: How are you getting to the next Activity if you aren't using an Intent?

Comment: 1) As to my knowledge not possible. 2) Why exactly would you want that, when it's as simple as it gets already?

Comment: You can do it via the [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus). You can send all kinds of `Objects` with it.

Comment: You can pass custom objects using Parcelable classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways: event buses, SharedPreferences, through global object (application class), database, simple file. But why?

Try direct and readable style first.

Comment: Thanks @Maxim G....!!!
I tried simple file and get the solution to my problem....!

Answer (score -1):

if you can't bundle the values you want to save in the Intent, then you could use the **SharedPreferences**. More information [here](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html)